# VSE: Are there ffmpeg trancode settings that would speed up video editing without a proxy?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I know I can do a proxy, and it works pretty well, but this question is about VSE editing **without** a proxy:

We often edit HD videos from a number of cameras with different framerates, so we have to transcode them to fix framerates before using VSE anyway.  Even if we edit a video individually, we find that some video sources are easier to edit than others (less choppy, lower latency during random seek).

Are there "ideal" encoding settings for `ffmpeg` (or another transcoder) that would make VSE respond quickly to random seeking and basic editing?

Here are a few options I can think of for tuning:

- codec *(usually we use x264 or x265)*

  - This post mentions transcoding to [Avid DNxHD](https://askubuntu.com/a/907515/1441797) for [Cinerella](https://cinelerra.org/), is that a good option for Blender, too?
- codec keyframe interval *(usually left default, so ~25-250 frames for x265)*
- video framerate *(usually we use ~30fps)*
- other considerations?

(In case it matters, we are using Blender v3.3 on Oracle Linux 8 with a Radeon RX 5500 on a quad-socket Xeon E7-4890v2.)